# How do I solve for the normalization constant of a discrete time-frequency Gabor atom?

Tags: time-frequency, normalization, gabor

Given the mathematical expression for the discrete Gabor time-frequency atom
$$g_{s,u,\omega,\theta}(n) = \frac{K_{s,u,\omega,\theta}}{\sqrt{s}} e^{-\pi(n-u)^2/s^2} \cos[2\pi\omega(n-u)+\theta]$$
where the variables are described in the original paper [here](http://mcl.usc.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/200908-Environmental-sound-recognition-with-time-frequency-audio-features.pdf) (page 6 of the PDF), how do I solve for the normalization constant $K_{s,u,\omega,\theta}$? My attempt was to solve for the normalization constant using the equation
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g_{s,u,\omega,\theta}(n)|^2\mathrm dn = \int_{0}^{N}|g_{s,u,\omega,\theta}(n)|^2\mathrm dn  = 1 $$
where $n$ is the time index and $N$ is the total number of samples in the atom, but I have not arrived at a solution. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrete squared L2 norm is a sum, not an integral:

$$
||g||^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |g(n)|^2 = 1
$$

To norm, we set $K = 1/||g||$ (rather than $1/||g||^2$).

I don't know if there's a closed form solution, as [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+e%5E%28n%5E2%29+from+0+to+N+-+1) can't even do $\sum e^{-n^2}$. The context usually implies translation invariance, so the result should be independent of $u$, but I can't tell for this paper. In practice we simply do

```
g /= sqrt(sum(abs(g)**2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was given the task of checking whether it can be solved theoretically or not, but to no avail. I guess this solution would suffice.